# Is there a way to use the condition of an If statement as its value?

Tags: sql, ms-access, optimization, conditional-statements

This could be a simple question, but it's one I've never seen answered before. Is there a way to use an if statement's condition as its value? This would be really useful in cases where lots of calculation is done to determine if a certain condition is met and if it is, that calculation is the result.

As an example:

```
if ( [intense calculation] > 0, [same intense calculation], 0)
```

I'm interested particularly with regards to SQL, as I'm working on a report in Access right now and so can't store the result of the intense calculation in a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if such a concept exists in the MS Access report world, but how about:

`MAX([intense calculation], 0)`

The obvious benefit of such an approach is that the calculation would only need to be done once.

Comment: And if you want a default value in case the variable is NULL there's NVL (in oracle) and co - sadly everyone likes to call that one different but still extremely useful and I think every DBMS has something like that.

Comment: and what if intense_calculation is lower than 0 ?

Comment: @mkk, then the result is 0, same as the poster's IF statement.

Comment: ahh forget about my comment :) my point was that you did not take into consideration the case when it is lower than 0, but of course this is the requirement - my bad, apologizes:)

Comment: Ah, good idea! Yes, the thing I was attempting to do was to avoid doing the calculation more than once. Unfortunately, "max" means something different in Access/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

One approach in most forms of SQL would be to move the main query to a sub-query, with the intense calculation column aliased and tested in the new outer query - like so:

```
select v.*,
       case intense_calc > 0 then intense_calc else 0 end as positive_calc
from (select [intense calculation] as intense_calc,
             [other columns]
      from ...) as v
```

Comment: Yup, I think this is the way to go. I was thinking about doing it this way, but wanted to see if maybe there was some obscure syntax that I didn't know about that could reference the condition. Thanks!